# What to declare react-router argument as in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to get set up with react-router using Typescript in a way which accepts a parameter.

In my `render` element I have

```
<Route path="/show/:id" component={TestComp} />
```

And I define `TestComp` as

```
const TestComp = ({ match }) => (
    <div>
        <h2>Showing specified ID: {match.params.id}</h2>
    </div>
)
```

However, VS Code underlines the `match` parameter (in the declaration of `TestComp`) and tells me

> Binding element 'match' implicitly has an 'any' type.

and it fails to compile.

Can anyone tell me as what type `match` should be declared? I've tried `RouteProps` but that doesn't work either. Looking in the index.d.ts, I think it's defined as `match<P>` but I'm not sure how to declare a parameter as being of a generic type.

**UPDATE**
Based on the comments to @TarasPolovyi's answer, I've added the following:

[image]

As you can see, this still has problems.

Comment: Did you imported `match` from `react-router`? Maybe that could explain some of your errors. You also need to declare the type from `TestComp`.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `react-router` v4 then import `RouteComponentProps` from `react-router-dom` and use type  `RouteComponentProps<RouteInfo>` - the argument name must be a match

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Typescript and React Router V 4.0 then the syntax is different.
You declare your Route as following:

```
<Route path="/home/:topic?" render={() => {
   return this.renderView(<ContentHolder />);
}} />
```

Then the Component is declared as following:

```
interface RouteInfo {
    topic: string;
}

interface ComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps<RouteInfo> {
}

class ContentHolder extends Component<ComponentProps> {

    render() {
        return (
            <Content>
                <h1 className="page-title">{this.props.match.params.topic}</h1>
            </Content>
        );
    };
};

export default withRouter(ContentHolder);
```

Then inside your `this.props.match.params` you get fully IntelliSense in both VS Code and IntelliJ

Answer (score 7):

First you need to import `match` from `react-router-dom`.

This is copy of my code generated from create react app:

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    match
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

You need an interface like this:

```
interface Identifiable {id: string; }
```

`match` is the thing which you need. Like this:

```
const TestComp = (mathedRoute: match<Identifiable>) => (
    <div>
        <h2>Showing specified ID: {mathedRoute.params.id}</h2>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install a package `@types/react-router`, which has types declaration for `react-router`. It contains an interface `match<P>`, so you can describe your property type using it.

Comment: I already have the typings for react-router. Could you be more clear on this? If I type  `const ShowCrawl = ({ match: match<P> }) =>`  then it underlines `match` with "'match' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here." and also underlines `P` with "Cannot find name 'P'."  So I'm obviously still not declaring it correctly.

Comment: You should define an interface like this: `interface Identifiable { public string id; }` and the change your match for something like this: `({ match: match<Identifiable> })`.
Obviously if your structure change to something more complex, you should change that interface accordingly (and the interface name ;) )

Comment: Also you can try to declare your react component as `const TestComp: React.SFC<TestCompProps> = (props) => {/* your code */}`. Where `interface TestCompProps = RouteComponentProps<YourProps>;` and `interface YourProps = { /* Your custom props here/ */ };`. That must be the most flexible way to do it.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot specify variables types as a part of object destructuring syntax. You should declare the type of the whole parameter, and then apply destructuring, which means that following construction should work: `const TestComp = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<RouteInfo>) => {/* ... */}`. `RouteComponentProps` is the interface which you should use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To specify prop type as `RouteComponentProps<T>`, then you can access with `match.params.your_prop`

```
<Route path="/show/:showId" component={TestComp} / >

<Link to={'/show/1'}>CLICK HERE</Link>

// or, use string interpolation with variable as below
<Link to={`/show/${id}`}>CLICK HERE</Link>
```

```
import React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

type Props = {
    showId: string;
}

const TestComp= ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<Props>) => {
    console.log(match.params.showId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways

```
const Container = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<{ showId: string}>) => {
 const { showId} = match.params.showId;
}
```

or

```
const Container = () => {
  const { showId} = useParams<{ showId: string }>();
}
```